# Typescript wrapping types

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

I have some factory method which is making some computations and manipulations. Also I have a generic method doSomething. I don't wanna to specify type for doSomething each time. I would like to do it once for factory method and then get it each time with already assigned type

```
function factory<T>(t: T){
// some computations

return {method: doSomething<T>} <- this is what I wanna do
}

// Generic
function<T extends object>doSomething(): T{
//complex stuff, a lot of lambdas
}
```

How from factory method I can return doSomething with allready assigned type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the type parameter of a generic function without calling it.  So `doSomething<T>` is not acceptable; only `doSomething<T>()` is allowed.  Luckily, you can just return a concrete function that calls the generic function with the proper type parameter specified.  Like this:

```
function factory<T extends object>(t: T) {
  // some computations
  return { method: ()=>doSomething<T>() } 
}

// Generic, note generic parameter comes after the function name
declare function doSomething<T extends object>(): T;
```

Let's see if it works:

```
const ret = factory({a: "hey"}).method();
// const ret: { a: string }
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!